# Spark yarn: get time elapsed per state transition

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

When running a Spark job, how can you get programmatically (in Scala/Java, probably in Spark's REST API) the time it took per state transition (from NEW -> ACCEPTED -> RUNNING)?

i.e. total time during state NEW, total time during ACCEPTED, total time during RUNNING

Comment: enabling Spark History Server will help you in visualizing the complete DAG of your job. See here for [more info](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact)